# Loading PDFs via PDF.js with API 30

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview, pdf.js, android-storage

API 30 introduced changes related to file access within a `WebView`:

```
/**                                                                                            
 * Enables or disables file access within WebView.                                             
 * Note that this enables or disables file system access only. Assets and resources            
 * are still accessible using file:///android_asset and file:///android_res.                   
 * <p class="note">                                                                            
 * <b>Note:</b> Apps should not open {@code file://} URLs from any external source in          
 * WebView, don't enable this if your app accepts arbitrary URLs from external sources.        
 * It's recommended to always use                                                              
 * <a href="{@docRoot}reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader">                           
 * androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader</a> to access files including assets and resources over  
 * {@code http(s)://} schemes, instead of {@code file://} URLs. To prevent possible security   
 * issues targeting {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#Q} and earlier, you should explicitly
 * set this value to {@code false}.                                                            
 * <p>                                                                                         
 * The default value is {@code true} for apps targeting                                        
 * {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#Q} and below, and {@code false} when targeting        
 * {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#R} and above.                                         
 */                                                                                            
public abstract void setAllowFileAccess(boolean allow);
```

An application utilizing PDF.js by first downloading a PDF and then displaying it via `"file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=${path/to/file}"` will no longer work. Forcing `setAllowFileAccess` to `true` is possible but discouraged.

`WebViewAssetLoader` is suggested as an alternative, however it appears to be geared toward use cases focused on loading local files from the `/assets` directory or `/res` directory.

**Questions:**

1. How can PDF.js be used to load a local PDF file considering the restrictions added in API 30?
2. Is there a way to use `WebViewAssetLoader` to load a file saved in the application's local storage?

Comment: Any luck with this? I tried the base64 approach and got it working, but large PDF's are not possible with that solution :/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader.InternalStoragePathHandler
It works pretty well for loading pdf stored in app's `files` dir.

Answering your questions:

1. Use [WebViewAssetLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader)
2. Use [InternalStoragePathHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader.InternalStoragePathHandler)

Comment: yes, but unfortunately it doenst fit for opening any pdf inside the storage (sdcard / local offline directory).